# Run Javascript function before calling Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

I am learning **Java Servlets** and I am working on a simple homework assignment. I have an **html** page containing a `form`, that is submitted to a **servlet**, does some processing, and uses a `printwriter` to render an html page with results.

Now, I want to add **Javascript**, which I am familiar with. Is there a way that I can write a Javascript function to validate data in the form, and if the data is valid, then call the servlet, otherwise, don't call the servlet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is just [form validation with Javascript](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm).

First you need to include a call to a Javascript validation function into the `onsubmit` attribute of your form. Something like:

```
<form name="myForm" action="YourServlet" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    ...
</form>
```

Then, if you're really familiar with Javascript, your validation function should be easy to create... Basically it's something like:

```
function validateForm() {
  //Check form fields:
  //If they're are correct return true,
  //otherwise return false...
}
```

If the validation function `validateForm()` returns false, the form won't never be submitted, that's to say, the servlet won't be called...

Note: usually you will have a validation function that actually calls other functions to check different parameters, as you can see at the end of [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php).